# How to improve the process of Running below SQL queries?

Tags: mysql

Problem:

I have below SQL queries and I need to update on each Server once and that too only when subStartDate Column is null and has DataType as timeStamp.

> Note:The below 2 queries should be run in Order:i.e first 1 should be run and then 2 must be run.

---

This query makes the datatype of sub_start_date column as timestamp with default value current_timestamp

## 1

```
alter X modify column sub_start_date timestamp default current_timestamp;
```

---

This query updates sub_start_date column value as start_date

## 2

```
update X set sub_start_date=start_date;
```

> Can this process be automated so that manual intervention can be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid manual process by altering column `sub_start_date` to do not accept `NULL VALUES`.

```
alter X modify column sub_start_date timestamp NOT NULL default current_timestamp;
```

This will remove the pain of altering table periodically.

Comment: What about the update query?I need to run both queries for that I need to check

Comment: What does `start_date` contain? If you alter the column like the one in my post, you will not need `update` query because it will always have default current timestamp value.

Comment: The start_date contains the data that needs to be updated everytime user has money.

Comment: In that case, set a cron that will periodically run and update the column.

Comment: A Code has been written that will update start_date.No need for crom

Comment: I meant, a code that will update `sub_start_date=start_date`. This should be set in cron. You can also do this when your `start_date` is inserted or updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138792/discussion-between-jason-arora-and-samir).